# Get newly created Activity NoteID using Web API

Tags: acumatica

I am pushing opportunity activities using Web API to Acumatica Partners Portal using Screen ID SP303020. I need to get newly created NoteID which is the uniqueidentifier in CRActivity table from Acumatica Partners Portal and store into my database so I do not push the same opportunity activities again and create duplicate.

Here is the code I am using to get new created Opportunity Activity NoteID, but I am not getting anything

```html
SP303020WS.Screen context = new SP303020WS.Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
context.EnableDecompression = true;
context.Timeout = 1000000;
context.Url = "https://sso.acumatica.com/Soap/SP303020.asmx";

SP303020WS.LoginResult result = context.Login(username, password);

SP303020WS.Content CR303020 = context.GetSchema();

context.Clear();

#region Push Activity to Partners Portal
SP303020WS.Content[] CR303020Content = context.Submit
 (
  new SP303020WS.Command[]
   {
    new SP303020WS.Value
    {
     Value = actiPartner.AcumaticaCaseID,
     LinkedCommand = CR303020.Opportunity.OpportunityID
    },
    new SP303020WS.Value
    {
     Value = actiType,
     LinkedCommand = CR303020.Activities.Type
    },
    new SP303020WS.Value
    {
     Value = actiCloud9.Subject,
     LinkedCommand = CR303020.Activities.Summary
    },
    new SP303020WS.Value
    {
     Value = actiCloud9.Body,
     LinkedCommand = new SP303020WS.Field { FieldName="Body", ObjectName="Activities"}
    },
    new SP303020WS.Value
    {
     Value = actiCloud9.StartDate.ToString(),
     LinkedCommand = CR303020.Activities.StartDate
    },
    CR303020.Activities.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
    CR303020.Actions.Save
   }
 );
#endregion

#region Getting Newly created Opportunity Activity NoteID

SP303020WS.Screen s2 = new SP303020WS.Screen();
s2.CookieContainer = context.CookieContainer;

SP303020WS.Content schema2 = s2.GetSchema();

var commands1 = new SP303020WS.Command[]
{
  schema2.Opportunity.OpportunityID,
  new SP303020WS.Field { FieldName="NoteID", ObjectName="Activities"},
};

var data = s2.Submit(commands1);

#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code snippet below:

```
SP303020.Screen context = new SP303020.Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "https://sso.acumatica.com/Soap/SP303020.asmx";

SP303020.LoginResult result = context.Login("***", "***");

SP303020.Content CR303020 = context.GetSchema();

var origActivities = context.Export
(
    new SP303020.Command[]
    {
        new SP303020.Value
        {
            Value = "OP00013116",
            LinkedCommand = CR303020.Opportunity.OpportunityID
        },

        CR303020.Activities.Type,
        CR303020.Activities.Summary,
        new SP303020.Field
        {
            FieldName = "NoteID",
            ObjectName = CR303020.Activities.Summary.ObjectName
        }
    },
    null, 0, false, false);

SP303020.Content[] CR303020Content = context.Submit
(
    new SP303020.Command[]
    {
        new SP303020.Value
        {
            Value = "OP00013116",
            LinkedCommand = CR303020.Opportunity.OpportunityID
        },

        CR303020.Activities.ServiceCommands.NewRow,

        new SP303020.Value
        {
            Value = "Note",
            LinkedCommand = CR303020.Activities.Type
        },
        new SP303020.Value
        {
            Value = "Test Note 3",
            LinkedCommand = CR303020.Activities.Summary
        },

        CR303020.Actions.Save
    }
);

var activities = context.Export
(
    new SP303020.Command[]
    {
        new SP303020.Value
        {
            Value = "OP00013116",
            LinkedCommand = CR303020.Opportunity.OpportunityID
        },

        CR303020.Activities.Type,
        CR303020.Activities.Summary,
        new SP303020.Field
        {
            FieldName = "NoteID",
            ObjectName = CR303020.Activities.Summary.ObjectName
        }
    },
    null, 0, false, false);

var newActivity = activities.FirstOrDefault(a => origActivities.FirstOrDefault(o => o[2] == a[2]) == null);
```